# How to add link in tabs in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a link in a Bootstrap tab.  I have 3 tabs and I want one of them where I will click and a new page will be opened. Please let me know how I can do it.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="google.com" id="btnRent" style="background: #f4762a;">Rent/Lease/PG/Shop</a></li>
```

And I am using this jQuery...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(#btnRent).click(function()
    {
        var go_to_url = "www.google.com";
        document.location.href = go_to_url;
    });
});
</script>
```

But it's not working.  I want to open a new page when someone clicks on the "Rent/Lease/PG/Shop" tab.

Comment: The element selector should be quoted ` $('#btnRent').click(function()`

Answer (score 1):

you can try inside your click function:

```
 window.location = url;
```

or `window.open(url);`

it should do the trick..

Answer (score 0):

you don't need javascript for that, just use the target parameter inside your 'a' tag like this:

```
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="https://google.com" target="_blank" id="btnRent" style="background: #f4762a;">Rent/Lease/PG/Shop</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create another "" element inside your tab "

"

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a><a href="http://www.google.com>Click here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want a direct click just do this

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com>Click here</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```